# PayPal sandbox IPN subscription payments not coming through?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have setup two sandbox accounts with PayPal.

owner@example.com as the main business account

buyer@example.com as the payee/client account

I have tested my IPN script through the sandbox IPN simulator, and it works.

Now I am trying to test a subscription button where buyer@example.com signs up for a 1 week free trial subscription to owner@example.com

I have turned on IPN notifications in the owner@example.com sandbox account and have created and saved a custom button with the `notify_url=http://example.com/ipn.php` value set in section 3 of the custom button creator.

And after creating a subscription with buyer@example.com and a payment to owner@example.com ... the data is being shown in the sandbox account when I log in, but no IPN notifications are being sent to my http://example.com/ipn.php as I had specified. And there is no ipn history being shown on the sandbox paypal account history, either.

Has anybody encountered a similar experience? I am not receiving anything from PayPal after sending the test payments via sandbox.

What gives?

Comment: having the same issue and facing much trouble ...

Answer (score 0):

With subscriptions you're going to need to configure IPN in the PayPal account profile.  It won't use the notify_url value for all of the payments on a profile.  It will only use the URL (if any) configured in the profile.

Comment: "configure IPN in the PayPal account profile" ... I can't enable IPN without configuring the IPN in the account profile.

Comment: Yes you can.  notify_url would override the setting in the profile, so a lot of times people just use that in their payment request without setting up a URL in the profile.  If you have a URL configured in the profile then that's where the IPNs for subscriptions would go.